# How can I reduce the size of my ns declaration in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I have to include a lot of declarations in  clojurescript namespace:

```
(:use-macros
    [webapp.framework.client.coreclient  
    :only [ns-coils sql log neo4j neo4j-1 sql-1 log
           watch-data  -->ui  <--data <--ui
           watch-ui remote  defn-ui-component
           container  map-many  inline  text
           div   img pre component h2 input
           write-ui read-ui container
           inline text admin ==data ==ui  -->ui  watch-ui <--ui
           <--data -->data remote inputcomponent <--
           h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 span  data-view-v2
           watch-data map-many inline text
           container <--pos <--id session-user-id select select-debug
           def-coils-app
           ]])
```

Is there any way to reduce this to something like:

```
(:use-macros
    [webapp.framework.client.coreclient])
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comparison to clojure where it would be possible to use :refer :all it is not possible in clojurescript. You can find the proper answer in here :

[Is it possible to use :refer :all in a ClojureScript :require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463469/is-it-possible-to-use-refer-all-in-a-clojurescript-require)

However, you can do is this:

```
(:require-macros 
  [webapp.framework.client.coreclient :as client])
```

And then you can refer to any macro in this namespace like this :

```
(client/div ... )
```

Comment: The reason I am doing this is so that I do not have to do the "client/div" type prefix every time I use an element

Comment: That's considered a bad practice and therefore it wasn't introduced to Clojurescript and it won't be. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/clojurescript/refer$20all/clojurescript/SzYK08Oduxo/p0bWhM5lftUJ