# Why doesn't figwheel pass the compiled app to the browser?

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, clojurescript, reagent

I'm using Leiningen 2.5.2 (Java 1.8.0_45-internal Open JDK 64-bit), and the reagent-template (i.e. `lein new reagent foo`).

This runs okay with `lein figwheel` as expected.

Next, the first thing I do is break out the "Views" functions into separate files and add them to the app namespace:

#### core.cljs snippet:

```
;; -------------------------
;; Views

(:require home-page)
```

#### home-page.cljs (whole file):

```
(ns foo.core)

(defn home-page []
  [:div [:h2 "Welcome to foo"]
   [:div [:a {:href "#/about"} "go to about page"]]])
```

When I go to view the app in the browser (chromium or firefox), it gets stuck at "ClojureScript has not been compiled!" despite seemingly compiling successfully in the terminal. If I enter commands in the figwheel REPL, I see the green Clojure logo when it is working in the browser, so I know it's connected.

I had this working in a reagent app some months ago--what happened? How *should* I separate my view code? (A single file is unmanageable; that's a lot of Hiccup.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have only the line `(:require home-page)` in core.cljs, this should be the culprit. The colon notation `:require` is only valid inside a namespace declaration with `ns`. Also, you declare the core namespace in the wrong file (home-page.cljs, not core.cljs). Take a look at [this article on namespaces in Clojure](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html) for a thorough explanation.

You will want the following in core.cljs:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [foo.home-page :as hp :refer [home-page]]))
.... more core.cljs code ...
```

and then simply in home-page.cljs:

```
(ns foo.home-page
  (:require ....reagent namespaces as needed ....

(defn home-page [] ....
```

Comment: Seems that :refer :all is not possible anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463469/is-it-possible-to-use-refer-all-in-a-clojurescript-require

Comment: You're right, sorry. I updated the code accordingly.